Verify a result from the paper "The Periodic Table of Primes"
Someone sent me this link to the paper "The Periodic Table of Primes".
I decided to see if I can verify one of their examples, so chose Example 8.

I used Mathematica with the command:
    Count[Table[PrimeQ[i],{i,2,2311}],True]

The result is $343$ (do not count $2$) and that is way off from their estimate.
Can someone verify my result or let me know if I am doing something wrong?

$2311$ is the $344$th prime

@Henry: Thanks, that seems to validate my result. I tried Prime[344] and indeed, it is $2311$.

And Example 7 claims the maximum prime gap in $[10000, 300000]$ is $281509 –
281431 = 78$, but it's actually $156007 - 155921 = 86$.  I don't think these are just accidental errors; the technical term for this paper is "nonsense".

@RobertIsrael: Thank you for verifying that - it was my next one on the list. I agree, this seems like another one of those wishful thinking and nonsense papers.

First sentence  of the abstract "Prime numbers are roots of integers" and the last sentence is "In other words, the 48 integers serve as the genes of primes, and among them 15 pairs serve as the genes of twin primes".  I think we can safely dismiss this paper as laugh-worthy.

@fleablood: Amazing that this got written up in https://www.msn.com/en-us/news/technology/breakthrough-in-prime-number-theory-demonstrates-primes-can-be-predicted/ar-BB1l14hQ. I wonder if it was an April Fool's joke.

The paper has been retracted.
